# Stop code when a condition is true

Tags: return, tcl, exit

I am trying to build a safety that will check for a condition that will either be true or false. This will be called multiple times through out a long bit of code. if the condition is true it will cause the rest of the code to stop. I cant seem to figure it out. Can someone point me in the right direction? By the way Exit will not work as it will close the whole program that I use.

```
proc _CheckEsc {} {
    if {condition is true} {
        return
    }
    return
}


proc testType {} {
    set TestResult 0
    while {$TestResult < 10} {
        _CheckEsc;
        incr TestResult
    }
    return; 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make `_CheckEsc` stop it's caller by using some of the more advanced features of `return`. In particular, we can use it to make `_CheckEsc` act itself like a `break` or a `return`.

This mechanism is very much like throwing an exception in other languages (and in fact you can regard Tcl as having special exception classes for `return`, `break` and `continue`, except things are rather more complicated than that under the covers).

### Making the caller's loop stop

```
proc _CheckEsc {} {
    if {condition is true} {
        return -code break
    }
}
```

### Making the caller return

```
proc _CheckEsc {} {
    if {condition is true} {
        return -level 2
        # Or, if you want to return a value from the caller:
        ### return -level 2 "the value to return"
    }
}
```

Note that the `-level` option isn't supported in Tcl 8.4 and before; that limits what you can do with it, but your use case works provided you do this instead:

```
proc _CheckEsc {} {
    if {condition is true} {
        return -code return
        # Or, if you want to return a value from the caller:
        ### return -code return "the value to return"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Will something like this works for you?

```
proc _CheckEsc {} {
    return {condition is true}; # I don't know what you have here
}

proc testType {} {
    set TestResult 0
    while {_CheckEsc && $TestResult < 10} {
        incr TestResult
    }
}
```

You can help us out by being more specific of what `_CheckEsc` does.